# Google Maps v3 kml polygon transparency in IE8

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-8, kml

Starting some time around March 13th, I started receiving bug reports from
users that my KML polygons were no longer transparent on Windows XP, and IE8.
I did notice Windows XP updates were applied before issues were first reported to me.

The transparency works fine on any other OS/Browser I have available to test.
(Windows XP with Chrome and Firefox, IE11 on Windows 7, Firefox and Chromium on Ubuntu 10)
Nothing has changed in my generation of the map, or the KML it uses.

I've been able to recreate this with a very simple test:
http://itic.occinc.com/googleMapTest.html
It uses this KML:
http://itic.occinc.com/test.kml

I've tried using different colors in the KML with more and less opacity/transparency.
For now I've disabled the polygon filling in my applications, but I'd like to re-enable that.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: the third party parser [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) [works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http://itic.occinc.com/test.kml) (where KmlLayer does not).

Comment: The example kml I used was simplified for demonstration.  I'm using the KML to show the polygons when there are too many or very complex polygons with lots of points.  Generating these and displaying them using google.maps.Polygon overlays resulted in Javascript generating "the script is too busy" popups.  An example of one of my complicated .kml files is  http://itic.occinc.com/test98.kml  (2803 polygons with 65992 points)  It took me about 5 minutes to run this through the geoxml3 parser for display in the map.

Comment: That is why KmlLayer uses tile based rendering.  geoxml3 is not a good solution for complex KML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was reported at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6540 and should be resolved

Comment: confirmed.  Thanks for the feedback.